# Rails 3.2.9 Intercept Asset Requests For Remapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 is there a way to intercept asset requests and remap the URL that is being requested.

For example, for a request for /assets/javascripts/app.js I would like to intercept the request and strip out javascripts/. I've tried in the application.rb

```
config.asset_path = proc { |path| 
    path.slice! 'javascripts/'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to intercept requests to assets and I highly doubt there's one or there'll ever be one at all.

Simply because it wouldn't work with compiled assets. What if the assets are on another server with a completely different software stack? For example if someone chooses to host the assets on Amazon S3, how could requests be intercepted at all?

If you really need this feature and you are self-hosting your assets the best way mght be configuring your web server to redirect the request.

Have a look at `RewriteEngine` for Apache or `HttpRewriteModule` for nginx. They provide mechanisms for URL rewriting. (I guess most production-grade web servers do have something simlar, too)